Common practices for acoustic dB SPL measurements, from pressure vs. time signal
I have not had formal training in acoustics and common practices in acoustic measurements.
Let’s say I have a microphone that gives me a Pa vs. time digitized signal.  I want to report the SPL in dB.
Is the only way to do this by some conversion to the frequency domain (either octave band filters or an FFT?  Or is there a way to do so from the time signal; without a frequency domain conversion?
If using an FFT, I could convert each fft bin to a dB value (ref 20uPa), or group the fft bins into octave bands and simulate the third octave levels that the filtered method would get me; which is what I have typically seen done.  If using a pure FFT though, do the db levels given by each bin have any common meaning when used “colloquially” ie. Could I say “the signal is 78dB at the 200Hz fft bin” and would people understand what I am saying?  Or are dB values always typically referencing an octave band; or the full A/L weighted spectrum?

The full standard for "official" sound level meters is IEC 61672 (parts 1, 2 & 3). How deep you want to dive into there depends on your application: are you just doing this as a hobby project or are you developing something that needs to hold up in court in a billion dollar lawsuit.
Generally the order of things is

Acquire signal
Apply proper scaling based on a calibration procedure (or risky assumption that the data sheet is actually correct)
Apply a frequency weighting filter (A, C, G, or Z)
Apply time processing (low pass filtering, accumulation and averaging).Th

This gives you a single number or the SPL as a function of time.
You can certainly report SPL in different frequency bands by following the same procedure in combination with a filter bank.
There are other variants of doing this, but that depends a lot on your specific application.

Let’s say I have a microphone that gives me a Pa vs. time digitized signal.

That's often the trickiest part: you need to make sure that the microphone is reasonably well calibrated and that nothing in the processing chain mucks about with the data. That can be quite tricky if you run a full operating system like iOS, Windows, Linux, Android, macOS, etc.
